# How to cretae a conda environment with basic libraries (numpy, pandas, scipy, matplotlib) pre-installled?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, virtual-environment

Every time I create a new Python environment through Anaconda, I have to install even the basic python libraries all the time. The numpy, pandas, matplotlib, etc. are such basic libraries that everyone needs them. Is there a sing;le command that can create the new environment whilst the mentioned libraries are pre-installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest way is to use command :

```
conda create -n env_full anaconda
```

It will install all packages that Anaconda includes

Second option is just listing packages you want to preinstall when creating env eg:

```
conda create -n new_env python=3.11 pandas scipy matplotlib
```

Remember you can always choose what distribution of package will be installed, simply by adding version of package like:

```
conda create -n new_env python =3.11 pandas=1.5, scipy=1.9.3
```

Adttionaly you can paste file with packages you want to be downloaded when creating new env with method:

```
--file 'dir to text file with packages'
```

You can read about options of cretaing envs in official docs:
https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/create.html

Edit:
Quick follow to my answer as bets practice sharing - I higly recomend cretaing file with packages you always use in your enviroment and just pass them with --file command when creating enviroment -> saves a lot of time :)

Comment: What's Continuum?

Comment: Hahaha, that's my typo :D continuum analitycs is old anaconda